# How can I set .innerHTML equal to two variables

Tags: javascript

For simplicity, I'm not going to show too much code, but the variables are set, and the following code is within a conditional. I'm just trying to show the var _offsetX and var _offsetY at the same time.

```
window.document.getElementById('cssposition').innerHTML = _offsetX _offsetY;
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `console.log(_offsetX, _offsetY)`? Looks like you're just debugging to me.

Comment: window.document.getElementById('cssposition').innerHTML = _offsetX +''+_offsetY;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
window.document.getElementById('cssposition').innerHTML = _offsetX +" " + _offsetY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `+` operator:

```
window.document.getElementById('cssposition').innerHTML = "X=" + _offsetX + " Y=" +  _offsetY;
```

Answer (score 0):

concat these two variables? ...innerHTML = "" + _offsetX + _offsetY;

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate two variables and then try out, but make a note this a redundant way,

```
window.document.getElementById('cssposition').innerHTML=_offsetX.concat(_offsetY);
```

Note: This ignores the space